# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error with DataSet type in C#

Tags: c#, dataset, runtime-error

Ok, so I did some research and I'm sure this site gets asked how to fix this error at least once a day. However, I attempted to debug but I still consider myself a novice at programming and am unable to solve this error after researching it. Here is the following code in C#:

```
DataSet set2 = new DataSet(); //Here, the DataSet is being created
clsData data2 = new clsData();     
set2 = data2.getData("SELECT * FROM TBLREFDES WHERE reportnote  like '%must installed%'"); //Here, the DataSet is being set to something so it is no longer null    
int num94 = (set2.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1); //Here is where the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" occurs
```

I have used an if statement to double check that both variables "set2" and "data2" are not null, and they aren't. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the table has rows?  What is returned from `getData`?

Comment: Just like @DonBoitnott asked, I would just about wager that checking the value of the dataset at runtime, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `set2.Tables[0]` us `null`. 
In other words: your query somehow doesn't return any result.

And also consider to not create `DataSet` before, cause it will be eventually assigned by `getData(..)` method.

Comment: Looks like this might be the cause. This is not my code, and the guy who wrote it left the company so I cannot ask him for help. Also, I am not familiar with DataSet. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @Jared.Rodgers: check for `null`